# Open source software for automotive ECUs?

Tags: open-source, car

Is there open-source software that can read and modify a car's [engine control unit (ECU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_control_unit) via the OBD connector (e.g., via an Blutooth OBD dongle)?

Comment: Any particular car make/model?

Comment: @SteveBarnes Nissan and Toyota, specifically. thanks

Comment: For reading, there's at least [AndrOBD](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.fr3ts0n.ecu.gui.androbd/). I'm not aware of any FOSS app with write support, though.

Comment: @Izzy Yes, I use that one; it's good.

Comment: Glad to hear! Maybe you want to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then, even if it's only a partly fit? Or does it offer write capabilities as well? I'm also curious as I plan to use OBD2 myself soon :p